# Imagery not displaying on certain mobile devices

Tags: android, ios, image, mobile

I've uploaded a new header image for our website and, although it displayed correctly across all mobiles when it went up, several people are only seeing a black square.

The code has been set up to pick out a video on desktops, the 1400x900 where possible and then switch to the smaller version where needed, so the only one that's actually called in on any page is the 1400 (or the video).

```
<ul class="list">
    <li>
        <span><img src="/img/writing-briefs-1400.jpg" width="1400" height="900" alt=""></span>
        <span style="background:rgba(153,153,153,0.9)">Theme. <small>#worklife</small></span>
    </li>
</ul>

<div class="intro">
    <div class="visual">    
        <video autoplay preload="auto" autoplay loop webkit-playsinline>
            <source src="/vid/sign-briefs.webm" type="video/webm">
            <source src="/vid/sign-briefs.mp4" type="video/mp4">                    
        </video>
        <img class="js_bg" src="/img/writing-briefs-1400.jpg" width="1400" height="900" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="detail" style="background:rgba(153,153,153,0.9)">
        <div>
            <h2>Theme. <small>#worklife</small></h2>
            <p>A lighthearted take on the corporate jargon that we encounter while working in a creative environment. First up, 'Writing Briefs'!</p>
            <a href="/news/news.html" class="view" data-label="Latest News">Loading&hellip;</a>             
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Despite this, and despite the fact I can see the image on my HTC One, users on iPhone and Samsung are not seeing it. But the code block is the same setup as another slide that is outputting fine. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Just a suggestion - try with not transparent background (alpha 1.0). Also when you want to make testing fast - you can test displaying your image in Safari (if in Safari is black, for iPhone it will be black too).